# Use Floyd-Warshall algorithm to find negative-weight circles

Tags: graph-theory, floyd-warshall, clrs, floyd-cycle-finding

To judge whether a graph contains negative-circles, after running the Floyd-Warshall algorithm, can I deal with the problem only by scanning the diagonal elements of the matrix to find whether it has negative elements. I dont't know how to prove it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be clear that if there is a negative value  in `M[i][j]` at any iteration during the algorithm then there is a path with negative cost from `i` to `j`. If `M[i][i]<0` then there is a negative cost path from `i` to`i`, since it is a closed path, it must contain  a cycle.

There are two cases:  either **it **  is a cycle, or you can find a `j` different from `i` in the path,
and partition the path into `p1=path(i,j),2) p2=path(j,j) p3= path (i,j)`. So either `p2` is a negative closed path, or `p1` union `p3` is a negative closed path. Take the one that is negative and apply the same argument until you do get a cycle, which must be negative

Conversely, if there is a negative cycle 'C' formed by subset of nodes `S` with sum of edges `T`, containing some node `i` then on the iteration in which FW has passed through all of the nodes in `S`, the value of `M[i][i]` must be at least as small as the cost of the path 'C' so `M[i][i]<=T<0`. Since FW is nonincreasing, `M[i][i]` stays negative until the end of the algorithm.